# Usage of TRANSLATIONS in angular2 for Internationalization?

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement internationalization but unable to get the usage of I18nSelectPipe OR I18nSelectPipe OR TRANSLATIONS.

The official docs of angular2 is very limited, so I googled and found one [implementation](https://embed.plnkr.co/BnCRsCfB1ZIMoQ4QT6Lg/) but they are not using anything from angular for translation. They have created their own package.

Can  you suggest some good example/reference for better understanding so that we can use more of angular2 pipes and constants.

Answer (score 2):

This app is using Angular 2 native translations: https://github.com/actimeo/simmage-ui.

There is a docs WIP about Angular 2 i18n: https://github.com/angular/angular.io/pull/2309

It is based on html tags. You can translate content of html tags by adding 'i18n' attribute to it.